# Redirección por cambio de ruta en la URL en htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirección

estoy intentando cambiar la url de mi web y no consigo dar con el código que hay que poner en el htacces para que se haga correctamente.
Esta es la URL vieja:

`www.mmisitio.com/griferia/roca/grifo-doble-canal-251-5.html`

Y esto es lo que me gustaría que saliera:

`www.mmisitio.com/grifos/roca/grifo-doble-canal-251-5.html`

Esta sería una estructura básica de mi web:

`www.mmisitio.com/griferia/roca/grifo-doble-canal-251-5.html
www.mmisitio.com/griferia/teka/grifo-canal-sencillo.html
www.mmisitio.com/griferia/jacob/grifo-barato-5.html
www.mmisitio.com/valvulas/metal/valvula-pila.html
www.mmisitio.com/valvulas/plastico/valvula-cisterna.html
www.mmisitio.com/tornilleria/laton/tornillo-plano-7.html
www.mmisitio.com/tornilleria/acero/rosca-plancha-8.html`

Esto sería un ejemplo mas o menos, tengo unas categorías principales como las que he puesto griferia, valvulas, tornilleria y dentro de ellas otras categorias, y por último dentro de estas últimas tenemos los productos correspondientes. Creo que se entiende bien, si no comentadlo y lo intento describir mejor.

Este es código htaccess que tengo en mi web:

```
**RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /griferia/ www.misitio.com/grifos/-------------he quitado el http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^misitio.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.misitio.com/$1 [L,R=301]--------------he quitado el http
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+).html$ ver_producto.php?recordID=$2
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ categorias_ver.php?cat=$1
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/$ categorias_ver.php?cat=$2
errorDocument 404 /error404.php**
```

A ver la redirección me la hace y yo navego por la web tranquilamente, pero si visito un sitio donde tenía un enlace a este producto me tira una url como esta:

```
www.misitio.com/grifos/roca/grifo-doble-canal-251-5.html?recordID=grifo-doble-canal-251-5`
```

Cuando debería salir solo esta:

```
www.misitio.com/grifos/roca/grifo-doble-canal-251-5.html
```

Espero que se entienda bien y que alguien sea tan amable de darme alguna orientación de por donde va el tema.
Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero que no mezcles mod_alias y mod_rewrite. mod_rewrite tiene prioridad, quiere decir que todos tus RewriteRules se van a ejecutar antes del Redirect, con `griferia/etcétera...` y se vuelven a ejecutar otra vez después del Redirect, con `grifos/etcétera...`.  Puedes hacer el redirect con mod_rewrite para evitar la vuelta, por ejemplo:

```
RewriteRule ^griferia/(.+)$ grifos/$1 [L,R=301]
```

El Redirect manda el querystring al cliente, porque los rewriterules ya lo han construido al momento del Redirect, por eso ves URLs así:

```
...roca/grifo-doble-canal-251-5.html?recordID=grifo-doble-canal-251-5
```

con los parámetros pegados al .html.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres hacer es que los enlaces de fuera, te vayan a la nueva URL Amigable, igual es mas aconsejable hacer un redirect 301. De esta forma todos los enlaces, entraran a la versión anterior y se van a redirigir a la nueva sin perder trafico ni posicionamiento.

Lo que no te puedo asegurar es que te funcione de manera generica con expresiones regulares, ya que nunca lo he probado así.

Mi entrada para el redirect 301 es

```
redirect 301 direccion_vieja direccion_nueva
```

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba que tienes habilitado `mod_rewrite`: si tienes control sobre el servidor puedes hacerlo (como root) con `a2enmod rewrite`, si no tienes control sobre el servidor tendrás que solicitar que lo habiliten (si no lo está).

El comando es:

```
Redirect 301 /griferia/ http://www.misitio.com/grifos/
```

De esta forma redireccionará cualquier url como `http://www.misitio.com/griferia/dondesea` a `http://www.misitio.com/grifos/dondesea`. Pero no funcionará con `http://www.misitio.com/griferia` (por no tener barra final).
Lo he comprobado en mi propio servidor sin problema.

Debes poner el protocolo ("http://"), si no puede interpretar la dirección de destino como relativa y duplicar el nombre de dominio.